# How to remove the frame of a matplotlib image and set background color to transparent

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can i remove that black frame of the map? And is it possible to change the background color within that frame from white to transparent?

[image: plot with black frame and white background]

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fname = 'germany.shp'

shapes = list(shpreader.Reader(fname).geometries())

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo(central_longitude=10.0))

ax.add_geometries(shapes, ccrs.PlateCarree(), edgecolor='none', alpha=1)

ax.set_facecolor((1.0, 0.47, 0.42))

ax.set_extent([6, 15, 47, 55])

plt.savefig("map.png", format='png', dpi=400, quality=95)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Try to add add the flag ```transparent=True``` in savefig

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn axis off with `plt.axis('off')` and save the figure transparent with `plt.savefig('name.png', transparent=True)`.

Edit: The borders and the background that you want to change are introduced by the cartopy GeoAxes. To change them use:

```
ax.background_patch.set_visible(False)   # Background
ax.outline_patch.set_visible(False)      # Borders
```

A reference example can be found [here](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/examples/hurricane_katrina.html).

Notice that the `transparent=True` keyword in `plt.savefig` is still needed.

Comment: "transparent=True" turns just the color outside of the frame to transparent and "plt.axis('off')" doesn't work. the frame is still there.

Comment: Ok, then the borders are patches of cartopy. Could you try with ```ax.outline_patch.set_linewidth(0)```

Comment: Thats it. Great! Any idea how to handle with that transparent background color?

Comment: It should be ```ax.background_patch.set_visible(False)```

Comment: Instead of setting zero-width borders, you can simply turn them off with ```ax.outline_patch.set_visible(False)```.